# Kill signal not delivered from one application to another

Tags: android, kill-process, taskkill, activity-manager

Hey I'm working on an application . In which i am killing other application from my application. But it does not work.
I am searching a lot and found many solution , But no one is working for me. here is my code.

```
             ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            for (int i=0 ; i<runningAppList.size() ; i++ ){
                am.killBackgroundProcesses(runningAppList.get(i));
               // runningAppList.get(i) is the package name of killing app
            }
```

Please tell me where is the problem. Or give me working solution.

Android Manifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Could you please show us the more code? If `runningAppList.get(i)` would have returned package name, the method would work.

Comment: killBackgroundProcesses will kill background processes not the process itself,  you need to kill the process itself `killProcess()` and AFAIK you can do that only for process that you own, or you have to be a sys app

Comment: yes the method runningAppList.get(‌​i) work properly.